# Issue with updating clicked table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an issue that has been vexing me for a while and I feel like I am so close. Here is the situation. I have a tableview that holds different calculus videos and I would like to give my students the ability to download the videos for playing offline. That part works fine. The problem I am having is that when the user clicks on the download button, the download button should hide and show an activity indicator as well as a progress bar (all of which are in a custom cell). I have two problems:

1) The download button does not automatically hide and show the activity view unless I scroll away from it and come back to it.

2) If I do scroll down all of a sudden random cells will not have the download button anymore.

This must be due to the fact that cells are being reused but I thought I was doing things properly although obviously there is a mistake. I will post the relevant code snippets below:

#### cellForRowAtIndexPath Code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VideoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let currentVideo = videos[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        cell.downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: "downloadButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        cell.video = currentVideo

        return cell
    }
```

#### Custom Table View Cell Code:

```
    class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var videoTitleLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
        @IBOutlet weak var customAccessoryView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var downloadButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        var video: Video? {
            didSet {
                updateUI()
            }
        }

        private func updateUI() {
            guard let video = video else {
                print("video should not be nil")
                return
            }

            videoTitleLabel.text = video.title

            if video.downloadStatus.isDownloading {
                progressView.hidden = false
                progressView.progress = video.downloadStatus.downloadProgress
                downloadButton.hidden = true
                activityIndicator.hidden = false
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            } else {
                progressView.hidden = true
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }

            if video.downloadStatus.isSaved {
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                progressView.hidden = true
                downloadButton.hidden = true
            }
        }
```

#### Download request

```
func downloadButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition) else {
        print("Error getting index path from button press")
        return
    }


    let section = indexPath.section
    let row = indexPath.row
    print("Button pressed at section \(section) and row \(row)")//correct row and section

    //Code to save Video to Documents directory goes here
    let currentVideo = videos[section][row]

    guard !currentVideo.downloadStatus.isSaved else {
        print("Video is already saved")
        return
    }

    guard let url = currentVideo.url else {
        print("Video not found...url is invalid")
        return
    }

    let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)

    Alamofire.download(.GET, url, destination: destination)
        .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in

            let progress = Float(totalBytesRead) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead)
             currentVideo.downloadStatus.isDownloading = true
            currentVideo.downloadStatus.downloadProgress = progress

        }.response { request,response,data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed with error: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Downloaded file successfully")
                currentVideo.downloadStatus.isDownloading = false
                currentVideo.downloadStatus.isSaved = true
                self.saveDownloadStatusInDefaultsForVideo(currentVideo, isSaved: true)
            }
            print("Files currently in the documents directory:")
            self.printDocumentsDirectoryContents() //file is there
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class `TableViewCell` you're setting the property `hidden` of `downloadButton` to `true` under certain circumstances.

If you want the button to be visible by default set the property explicitly to `false` when reusing the cell

Comment: That was helpful and a great suggestion. How simple! I still have the issue that the activityView is not showing when the download button is pressed. Any idea where I am going wrong with that part?

Comment: Put all the properties into a predictable state

Comment: I initialized the cell properties in the awakeFromNib() method but according to my thinking when the video.downloadStatus.downloadProgress property changes (inside of the Alamofire progress closure), shouldn't the property observer inside of TableViewCell see that and update the UI at that point? The only way I can get the UI to update is if I tell the tableview to reload inside of the Alamofire progress closure which I know is not a good solution.

Comment: No, I mean *put all the properties into a predictable state* in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`